# Continued fraction approximation

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $\theta\in\Bbb{R}_{\gt0}$.

A) Prove that the convergents for the continued fraction expansion of $\theta$ give us better and better rational approximations to $\theta$.

B) Suppose $\theta\notin \Bbb{Q}$. Prove that the convergents $a_n/b_n$ from the continued fraction expansion of $\theta$ form an alternating series of better and better rational approximations to $\theta$: $$\frac{a_1}{b_1}\lt\frac{a_3}{b_3}\lt...\lt\theta\lt...\lt\frac{a_4}{b_4}\lt\frac{a_2}{b_2}$$

I feel if I could do A then B probably follows somehow, and logically it makes sense, but no idea how to prove either!

Comment: There is a small potential exception to A), when the expansion terminates. It  depends on what you mean by "better and better."

Comment: Prove $B$ first. Use the recurrence that $a_n$ and $b_n$ satisfy, to show (`use induction`) that the odd terms increase, while the even terms decrease. Then take the difference between an even term and an odd term and bound it by $\frac{1}{b_nb_{n+1}}$

Comment: but I don't have a recurrence, just that they form the convergents for the continued fraction expansion of some theta...I need to be more general